# apigee key store and certificate upload issues

Tags: keystore, apigee

On my free trial account (cvtf1), I had a key store that is working fine since many months with self signed certificates. I tried today to create a new key store (Bca...) by uploading client key and certificate. But the upload fails with:
Upload keys

```
{
  "code" : "messaging.config.beans.CertNotFound",
  "message" : "Cert with name : /tmp/extract6784335744378261087.tmp/myCert.pem not found in key store : {1} in env : {2}",
  "contexts" : [ ]
}
```

Please note that I've checked the JAR upload is valid. If I replace my new cert+key with the old one by application the same process (and names), it works fine.

The differences are in the certificates:

**Old one working fine:**

```
  Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption - Public-Key: (1024 bit)
  Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
  Valid for ten years
```

**new one - failed:**

```
  Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption - Public-Key: (2048 bit)
  X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: critical
                TLS Web Client Authentication
  Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
  Valid for one day
```

I respect the limit of 2048 bits. Is-there any reason why it fails?

Another question: Do you support TLS 1.2 between Apigee Proxy and  the target endpoints?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Regards

Fr

Answer (score 1):

Apigee Edge supports key sizes up to 2048 bits.

Can you do the following openssl commands to verify if the md5 of the cert and the key are same :

openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in certificate.crt | md5
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in privateKey.key | md5

If the md5 is the same then the key belongs to the cert.

Comment: I tried to upload the same 2048 bits cert with validity of one day and was able to upload the jar to the keystore successfully. So, it doesn't seem that the validity of the cert or the number of bits is the issue here. Could you pass on the cert and key to divya@apigee.com  for me to further investigate the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Apigee Edge currently uses Java 6 which does not support TLS 1.2. Best way to confirm this is try TLSv1 with your new certificate.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Will not use TLS 1.2 so. Need to downgrade my backend implementation to TLS1.1.

Answer (score 1):

In your descriptor.properties inside the "jar" did you specify just the certificate file name or the complete path? Can you specify just the certificate and private key file name without the path?

Kind regards,

PB

Comment: Description of my archive:META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
myCert.pem
myKey.pem
META-INF/descriptor.properties and descriptor contains cert=myCert.pem and key=myKey.pem

Answer (score 0):

To all:
- In the jar: 2 files => cert and key
- Files are myCert.pem and myKey.pem (as specified in META INF / Descriptor)
- The built archive works fine with cert and key when 1024 size is used (so I believe my build process is valid)
- For cert / key md5 uniqueness: valid. I always check with (openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in myCert.pem | openssl md5 ; openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in myKey.pem | openssl md5) | uniq
- thanks for the answer about TLS1.2.

It really seems the issue is about the upload of the cert file. When I upload such a cert, could the "not find" be raised due to constraint on the cert TTL (one day)?

Regards

Fr

Answer (score 0):

Topic closed - issue found - extended attribute with OID as long integer is the root cause